# algorithm2e - Bug (?) with \SetKwSwitch

Tags: algorithm2e

The following M(not)WE should work. Did I find a bug ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetKwSwitch{Switch}{Case}{Other}{Switch}{:}{Case}{Other}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Switch{X}{
        \Case{1}{A}
        \Other{Other}
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No bug: `\SetKwSwitch` requires *nine* arguments and you only supply eight of them so the `\par` generated by the blank line is taken as ninth. And `\par` is illegal in the context where the ninth argument is used.

```latex
\newcommand{\SetKwSwitch}[9]{% #1=\Switch #2=\Case #3=\Other #4=switch #5=do #6=case #7=otherwise #8=endcase #9=endsw
%       \algocf@newcmdside{#1}{3}%
        \algocf@newcmdside@koif{#1}%
                {\KwSty{#4}\algocf@scond\ArgSty{##2}\algocf@econd\KwSty{#5}\ifArgumentEmpty{##1}\relax{ ##1}\algocf@block{##3}{#9} {##4\relax}}%
```

The manual has a description where the last (symbolic) argument is not braced, so there is a bug, but only in the documentation. On page 39, start of section 11.6, you read

```
 \SetKwSwitch{Switch}{Case}{Other}{switch}{do}{case}{otherwise}{endcase}endsw
```

but it should be

```
\SetKwSwitch{Switch}{Case}{Other}{switch}{do}{case}{otherwise}{endcase}{endsw}
```

Fixed example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetKwSwitch{Switch}{Case}{Other}{Switch}{:}{Case}{Other}{EndCase}{EndSwitch}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Switch{X}{
        \Case{1}{A}
        \Other{Other}
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the doc too quickly. :-(